# Avoid anonymous users in webpages

Tags: php

I have made a little website with signup, login and home page. I want to make sure that people cant enter the home page without logging in. I managed to do it to the index page so that if someone who hasn't logged in comes, it will include the login page and if some one who has logged in came, it would include the home page with include function. I would like to know another way to so it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well I think that that is a good way to do it. Every 'solution' to the posed problem basically comes down to that so... If you place that in a file `checklogin.php` or sth and you include it in every page you got you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution with includes is a reasonable approach.

Another approach would be to redirect to the login page.  When somebody comes who is not logged in, they would get redirected to the login page (a 302 temporary redirect would be best).  The URL they would see in their browser would be the URL of the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be using redirection, so when you find out user isn't logged in, redirect to logging page, and after logging, redirect back from where the user came.

[PHP header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/login.php"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();
?>
```

I think this way may be little more proper for search engines, which will not index inaccessible pages as "Log in" pages (correct me if I'm wrong :))

Comment: Don't forget the `exit()` after header - technically, PHP will carry on executing until the browser receives the redirect and sends the resultant request.